# Transform JSON object to two-dimensional array (heatmap)

Tags: javascript, json

I have data in a JSON object in the form of (errors are errorcodes, each number replaces a specific error message):

```
var obj = [{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-16 16:04:31.000000000",
    "error": "8022"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-16 16:04:41.000000000",
    "error": "8022"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-16 16:04:51.000000000",
    "error": "8008"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2018-12-16 16:05:02.000000000",
    "error": "3005"
  }, ...]
```

Now I want to do a heatmap plot like this:

[image]

from the errors with x-axis beeing the timestamp axis and y-axis the categorical error codes.

So the heatmap array should look like (the axes are here x=time and y=error code and the numbers the sum of the occurred errors).

```
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, ... ],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0,  ...],
  ...]
```

x-axis (horizontal): all occurring timestamps in the jsonobj

y-axis (vertical): all occurring errorcodes in the jsonobj

However, I can’t figure out how to prepare my data to get the needed heatmap (2d) array. I tried map and reduce functions to rearrange my JSON object, but that did not bring me close to the heatmap array.

This is what I have tried:

```
var o = jsonobj.reduce( function (acc, curr) {
    acc[curr.error] = acc[curr.error] || [];
    acc[curr.error].push({[curr.timestamp]:1});
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(o);
var a = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) {
    return {error: k, timestamp: Object.assign.apply({}, o[k])};
});
console.log(a)
```

Now I have an array containing the timestamps where an error occurred timestamp:1, but not a timestamp:0 where no error occurred (but the timestamp appeared elsewhere in the data with some other error).

Long-term goal is to create the needed z-matrix for a heatmap using plotly.js.

Comment: What's your desired output object? Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I updated the post. I want to plot this data with plotly.js, so x-axis is time, y the different errors and z the # of error occurrences in the JSON object.

Comment: Do you need a separate variable to store the Array of timestamps? From the looks of your heatmap array, it does not have anything related to the corresponding timestamp values, other than setting 0 on specific indices.

Comment: Please provide your desired output from the given example array of object.

Comment: Hi there, it is provided: Please see "So the heatmap array should look like...." and the provided image.

Comment: Yes, maybe I need a separate variable to store all occurring timestamps in order to map to 0 if no error "8002" e.g. occured at this timestamp othherwise 1. I try to generate the z-matrix needed for the plotly.js heatmap (x=all timestamps and y= all errors have to be provided as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should do it and create your 2d array:

```
console.log('Start');

jsonobj = [
{
    'timestamp': '2018-12-16 16:04:41.000000000',
    'error': '8022'
},
{
    'timestamp': '2018-12-16 16:04:41.000000000',
    'error': '8022'
},
{
    'timestamp': '2018-12-16 16:04:51.000000000',
    'error': '8008'
},
{
    'timestamp': '2018-12-16 16:05:02.000000000',
    'error': '3005'
}
]

console.log('JSON Array');
console.log(jsonobj);

var errorTimestampMap = jsonobj.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    if (acc[curr.error + curr.timestamp]) {
        acc[curr.error + curr.timestamp] += 1;
    } else {
        acc[curr.error + curr.timestamp] = 1
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log('Error Code/Timestamp Map');
console.log(errorTimestampMap);


var uniqueErrors = jsonobj.map(function (err) {
    return err.error;
}).filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return index == array.indexOf(value);
});

console.log('Array with unique error codes');
console.log(uniqueErrors);

var uniqueTimestamps = jsonobj.map(function (err) {
    return err.timestamp;
}).filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return index == array.indexOf(value);
});

console.log('Array with unique timestamps');
console.log(uniqueTimestamps);


var matrix = []

for (let i = 0; i < uniqueErrors.length; i++) {
    matrix.push(new Array(uniqueTimestamps.length).fill(0));

    for (let k = 0; k < uniqueTimestamps.length; k++) {
        if (errorTimestampMap[uniqueErrors[i] + uniqueTimestamps[k]]) {
            //console.log(errorTimestampMap[uniqueErrors[i] +     uniqueTimestamps[k]]);
           matrix[i][k] = errorTimestampMap[uniqueErrors[i] + uniqueTimestamps[k]];
        }
    }
}
console.log('Matrix');
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Nice, that's perfectly what I was looking for!